# Converting svg with image element to html canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm just trying to convert svg to html canvas, it works fine until i use image element in svg, if i use image elements means `canvg` is not working.

This is the code which i used to convert svg to canvas

```
var svgCanvas, context, svgCanvasElement, link;
svgCanvas = $('<canvas id="svgCanvas" width="250px" height="25px" style="display:none;"></canvas>');
context = svgCanvas[0].getContext('2d');
svgCanvasElement = $(svgCanvas)[0];
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var svgElement = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");
var svg = serializer.serializeToString(svgElement[0]);
var canvgMethod = new canvg(svgCanvasElement, svg);
```

Here not working [JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vky7b/2/).

**NOTE :** This code working fine for other elements like circle,rect,polygon and etc. Here is working [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vky7b/3/) with circle element.

How to overcome this issue and how can i convert this image element into canvas?
Any Suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to convert the image into a data URL. What you pass to canvg must be complete in a single file it can't have external references.

I can show you steps to see an image work. Start from this...

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image xlink:href="paste your data URL in here" height="75" width="75" y="27.5" x="29.5"></image>
</svg>
```

1. goto http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php
2. Select retrieve from a URL
3. Enter http://archiveteam.org/images/thumb/4/40/Google_Logo.png/800px-Google_Logo.png as the URL
4. Replace the output in the place indicated above (it's too big to include here)
5. Paste the whole lot above into the test [box here](http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/index.htm)
6. You're done, see the result on the left. Note I've only tested this on Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please edit my fiddle sample and make it work or else can you post some code here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vky7b/5/ this is my updated fiddle with your instructions but it doesn't work for me. Is there is any wrong thing i did or else did i missed anything here.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/xvQHb/3/

It's done using `canvg` plugin <kbd>[Reference](https://code.google.com/p/canvg/#sthash.Zb8VO3cv.dpuf)</kbd>

```
//load a svg snippet in the canvas with id = 'drawingArea'
  canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), '<svg>...</svg>')
```

Comment: @karthik Does this answer your query?

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. Can you Please make my fiddle to work for your answer.

Comment: What UA are you using. It's possible you're simply experiencing something not implemented in that UA.

Comment: @wizkid its working in fiddle but it doesn't work in html and it throws an "SyntaxError" in canvg.js

Comment: @wizkid, I got the this error message   :                                                                                                                          Unhandled exception at line 136, column 5 in http://localhost:21683/jsFiles/canvg.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError